# Mono C# FileChooserButton set to show only .tar.gz files

Tags: c#, linux, gtk, monodevelop, gtk#

How can I create a `FileChooserButton` that shows only `.tar.gz` files on MonoDevelop C# GTK+?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public MainWindow () : base(Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
{
    Build ();

    FileFilter filter  = new FileFilter();
    filter.Name = "tar.gz files";
    filter.AddPattern("*.tar.gz");
    filechooserbutton1.AddFilter(filter);
}
```